# Electron - How to setup db with sqlite in Windows

Tags: database, windows, sqlite, electron

I have created an electron app, and built it with electron-builder. It creates a package in the dist folder, which I am able to install and then run the resulting application.

I have a sqlite database in the root folder of my project, with some data in it. But when I package and then run the exe file, it seems not to connect to the database or it appears empty. If I simply run the project with electron without packing, it is able to connect to the database and make use of the data.

Also, if visit the installation folder, there I find a copy of the database I had in my application but without any rows in it. Inside an .asar folder, there is a database populated as I would want but this one I supposedly cannot edit.

Would you have any pointers on what could be causing this? How can I properly connect to the database I have in the root folder of my project using sqlite, sequelize, windows and electron?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also facing the same issue.. any solution? @iagomr

Comment: Sorry, it was long time ago. I don't remember if there was even a solution any longer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ensure that `electron-builder` doesn't pack the database file into the app ASAR (use the [`asarUnpack` option](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#configuration-options)).
2. If your packaged app needs to modify the database then have it copy the file to the location returned by [`app.getPath('userData')`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetpathname) and work with that copy. Your app generally does not have permission to write to the directory in which it is installed.